# Frothing issues in coffee machines

Tags: espresso-machine, froth

I have an expresso machine of Morphy Richards, which I have been using for quite some time.

The problem which I encounter is that the froth formed from its nozzle doesn’t stay for long, like it stays for a few minutes only. Does it mean that my machine has gone haywire or does this happen with almost all of the regular small coffee machines.

Should I instead  purchase a frother for the same or are there any other ways to rectify the problem.

Comment: Welcome! Two questions: a) Does your machine „automatically“ froth the milk or is it a „wand“ type of frother? b) Have you changed brands of milk lately?

Comment: 1) It’s wand type one...the machine has a nozzle attached sideways and a regulator to control the force. 2) No , I have been using the same milk brand as far as remember.. @Stephie

Comment: The fat content and viscosity of the fluid impact the life of your bubbles. I think if you're not doing anything different, it will be the size of the bubbles impacting their life. Are they larger? Perhaps your steam wand is blocked, have you tried cleaning it?